# What algorithm gives more accurate results xgboost or lightgbm?

Tags: boosting

LightGBM builds trees much faster than XGBoost. Though which algorithm works better in terms of accuracy in general and for specific tasks such as regression, classification in your experience?

Answer (score 2):

There is no one method that works better in general, not even when you restrict your problems to classification or regression. See the [no free lunch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem).

Comment: That does not mean it is a bad question.

Comment: I am not necessarily saying it is a bad question. (I am not the downvoter.) I tend not to answer bad questions.